# Shared library using v8 is incompatible with statically linked v8?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, v8, static-linking, chromium-embedded

Here's some backstory to the real problem:

I am working on a project using the [Chromium Embedded Framework](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) (CEF) and [v8](https://code.google.com/p/v8/) to provide native C++ function bindings to JavaScript running in an embedded browser.

What I'm trying to do, specifically, is construct a `v8::ObjectTemplate` before any pages or contexts are loaded, then in CEF's `OnContextCreated` callback, create a new instance of that template and add it as a property on the global `window` object.

The problem is that CEF's API wraps v8 contexts and values, giving you a (smart) pointer to an interface, completely hiding the fact that it's using v8 under the covers. Due to limitations imposed by CEF, the project would get messier if I were to use CEF's wrappers, so I would rather get v8 working. Here's a slimmed-down version of my implementation of CEF's `OnContextCreated` callback:

```
void ContextHandler::OnContextCreated(
  CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
  CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
  CefRefPtr<CefV8Context> context)
{
  context->Enter();

  v8::HandleScope scope;
  v8::Handle<v8::Context> v8context = v8::Context::GetCurrent();
  v8::Handle<v8::Object> window = v8context->Global();
  // _appObj is a v8::Handle<v8::ObjectTemplate> member of ContextHandler
  window->Set(v8::String::New("app"), _appObj->NewInstance());

  context->Exit();
}
```

Now, note that while CEF uses v8 under the covers, it does not expose it through its API. Therefore, the only way to retrieve the v8 version of a context is to use `v8::Context::GetCurrent()`, which in theory should return the `v8::Context` being wrapped by `CefV8Context`.

Also note that in order for this to compile, I need to compile and link a *separate* v8 (static) library, once again because CEF does not expose v8 through its (dynamic) library.

**So here's the problem**:

Upon running the project and hitting the call to `v8::Context::GetCurrent()`, it crashes with a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error somewhere in the v8 library. Upon further research, I have confirmed that according to CEF's API, we *are* in a context after the call to `context->Enter()`, but according to v8's API, we *are not* in a context, which explains the error.

From my extremely limited experience with C/C++ libraries, this seems to imply to me that CEF's v8 code and my v8 code are running in separate memory spaces. v8 is a static library, and CEF is a dynamic library, so would that have any effect on it?

What I'd like to know is why this is happening, and what can I do to fix this or work around this?

PS: I'm building this using C++11 and clang on Mac OS X through XCode, but this problem plagues VS2012 on Windows as well.

Comment: The v8 you link statically has no relationship with the v8 that CEF uses.  This isn't a different address space, but the two instances of the library (the one used inside CEF, and the one you statically link) do not know about each other.  Fortunately CEF is open source, so you can examine where CEF's v8 library is (and how it is loaded), and even add in "backdoors" if need be.  However, glancing at the ` CefV8Context`, I see it has a `GetGlobal()` method, which has a `SetValue()` method override that takes a key/value pair.  Ie, I'm seeing the interface you seem need within CEF?

Comment: @Yakk, `GetGlobal()->SetValue()` will only take `CefV8Value`s (CEF's wrapped implementation of `v8::Value`) and CEF imposes limitations on what you can do with them, thus using v8 directly. As to backdoors - CEF does a lot of crazy stuff when compiling it, and as a result, CEF methods can only return primitives, pointers, and other CEF classes. Final point: how would you suggest I go about using the "same" v8 as CEF?

Comment: I would either figure out how to use `CefV8Value` to do what I want, or extend `CefV8Value` to do what I want, or figure out how to generate a back door into `v8` from CEF, in rough order of increasing desperation and increasing likelihood to cause problems down the road.

Comment: @AustinHyde: Did you manage to solve this issue? I have the same issue now. Can you pls post the solution? Thanks!!!

Comment: @user3 Nope, never did figure it out. I believe I just sucked it up and worked with CEF. Here's the code from that project, if it helps at all: https://bitbucket.org/libalchemy/libalchemy

Comment: @Austin Hyde: Thanks for the update. I am exploring this option for integrating nodejs with CEF. Now, i have working code. I am building CEF with "V8_SHARED" option and link libcef.dll.lib to node.dll, this way i have all V8 symbols loaded to node.dll without separate compilation.

Comment: @user3 Unless you have a actual requirement to use CEF with node, it's probably far easier to use https://electron.atom.io/ or https://github.com/electron/brightray. I believe brightray is roughly equivalent to CEF

Answer (score 0):

To access the V8 VM used by CEF, you will have to build CEF yourself.  The libcef.dll is simply C++ to C to C++ proxy to the "real" libcef, which is a static library.  When you compile CEF yourself, you can change your programs to link to that static library rather than the import library for the DLL.

By doing this, you are now required to link to all the same static libraries to which the DLL had to link.  This includes V8.  This will now allow direct access to the same V8 that CEF is using.  It also removes the C++ to C to C++ translation code that the CEF DLL used to interface with the real CEF code.  This will also give you direct access to WebCore/WebKit, Chromium, V8, and any other libraries used by those, when you want or need it.

Refer to CEF's build instruction: https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding

Once build, the library you want to link to for CEF is libcef_static.lib.